# How to make only subsubsections visible in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to make a slide in beamer presentation that will have only subsubsections listed, so one can click and jump to interesting topic.

For my table of contents (the main one) I suppressed subsubsections with:

```
\tableofcontents[subsubsectionstyle=hide]
```

Then, for my 'mini table of contents' I have the following now:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \tableofcontents[sections={4},sectionstyle=hide]
\end{multicols}
```

The problem is, when I add `subsectionstyle=hide` it also hides subsubsections and I get big fat nothing.

Is there a way to have only subsubsections displayed without the subsection?

Comment: How about `\subsection*{subsection name}\refstepcounter{subsection}`?

Comment: Well, it works for me now, but I decided to hide subsections in the 'main' table of contents too.

But thanks, that's good enough for me. ;)

Comment: If you want, you can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shown here in `article` (not `beamer`).  The implementation is done manually, but it could be codified in a macro, if there were many of them to do.  I used a `\subsection*{SS1}\refstepcounter{subsection}` in lieu of a `\subsection{SS1}`, so that the subsections would not receive numerical headers, but the counters would nonetheless be advanced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{S1}\refstepcounter{section}
Section

\subsection*{SS1}\refstepcounter{subsection}
Subsection

\subsubsection{SSS1.1} subsub 1
\subsubsection{SSS1.2} subsub 2
\subsection*{SS2}\refstepcounter{subsection}
Next subsection

\subsubsection{SSS2.1} subsub2.1
\end{document}
```

[image]